# How to make JavaScript fetch request from a react app docker container to a Rails API docker container within the same network?

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, fetch

I have a couple of docker containers within a network. A container with a frontend react project and another container with a Rails API. I'm looking to make a request from the react project container to the Rails API but the fetch API continues to run into this error:

> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

---

React Code

```
function App() {

...
  async function apiRequest() {
    const options = {
      headers: myHeaders,
      method: requestMethod,
    }

    formData.append('username',username);
    formData.append('password',password);

    if (requestMethod === "POST") {
      options.body = formData
    }

    let requestStr = "http://user-api:3000/api/users/";
    let apiRequest = await fetch(requestStr, options)
    let data = await apiRequest.json()
    console.log(data)
  }
...
}
```

Dockerfile Frontend (React app using Vite)

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm i
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Dockerfile Rails API

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1

ENV APP_HOME /rails-docker
# Installation of dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq \
  && apt-get install -y \
      # Needed for certain gems
    build-essential \
         # Needed for postgres gem
    libpq-dev \
    # The following are used to trim down the size of the image by removing unneeded data
  && apt-get clean autoclean \
  && apt-get autoremove -y \
  && rm -rf \
    /var/lib/apt \
    /var/lib/dpkg \
    /var/lib/cache \
    /var/lib/log
# Create a directory for our application
# and set it as the working directory
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
# Add our Gemfile and install gems
ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install
# Copy over our application code
ADD . $APP_HOME
# Run our app
CMD RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV} bundle exec rails db:create db:migrate db:seed && bundle exec rails s -p ${PORT} -b '0.0.0.0'
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    container_name: movie-db
    image: postgres
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  frontend:
    container_name: movie-dojo-frontend
    build: ./movie_dojo
    image: "josephse91/movie-dojo-frontend"
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
  user-api:
    container_name: user-api
    build: ./user_api
    image: "josephse91/rails_api"
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/Rails-Docker
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true

volumes:
  postgres:

networks:
  default:
    name: "movie-dojo-network"
```

I've tried to place the rails API container name as the host within the fetch call but I haven't had any luck. Any advice?

Comment: React apps run in the browser. Your request URL should be `http://localhost:3000/api/users`

Comment: You'd need to add CORS support to your Rails app or if your React app was made using `create-react-app`, configure the proxy in `package.json`... `"proxy": "http://user-api:3000/"` and make local requests to `fetch("/api/users")`

Comment: Thanks so much @Phil - After applying localhost, I ran into the cors permission problem. Just as you suggested, I added CORS support to the Rails app using the following instruction:
[add cors support](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/rails-cors-guide/)

There were multiple ways in the article. I created a cors.rb file after installing the rack-cors gem